# SQL Query doesn't get executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I'm trying to make a very basic comment system in PHP.
The problem is that when I submit the form, the new row doesn't get inserted in my MySQL table.
This is my code (, could someone please check what's wrong?):

```
<?php
$act = $_POST['act'];
if($act == 1) {
    $m = $_POST['message'];
    $m = strip_tags($m);
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string($m);
    $name = "Anonymous"; //Static username for demonstration purposes
    $date = "2012-7-28"; //Static date for demonstration purposes

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (name, message, date) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$date')");
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>

<form action="comments.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: what's the error? I guess there's some issue with your table name or field names...

Comment: @DCoder This project is just a small one, and it's more of a personal project, so I'm fine with mysql_* functions for now. Didn't know they where deprecating, since most tutorials still use them.. Anyway, I'm might look into that PDO more deeply, thanks!

Comment: Say, can you tell us how the table you're trying to write to is structured? With variable types, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem rests with the escaping, or rather the 'non-escaping' of the column names. Did you know that 'date' is a function name in mySQL?

Try putting all table and column names in backticks.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`name`, `message`, `date`) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$date')");
```

Also, for further reference, posting the error message never hurts looking for the answer.
Other than that, I can't find anything particularly wrong with your query.

Edit: DUH! I missed something obvious.
Please execute 'mysql_select_db('name_of_database'); prior to the query.
Otherwise it won't know where to look for the table you're specifying.

For the sake of completeness (as Michael Besteck pointed out), it is necessary to execute 'mysql_real_escape_string' only AFTER the connection has been established.

That is, because the 'escape_string' relies on the encoding of the connection to determine which characters need to be escaped and how.

Comment: Column names do not necessarily need to be escaped, unless they contain reserved words or weird characters, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but is there a way to retrieve the error manually? I didn't an error when posting the form.

Comment: Date is a function name, and it's never a bad idea to 'escape' the column and table names.

Comment: @ATaylor: it's never a bad idea, but it won't solve the issue. Date can be used with no problem: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html "MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them."

Comment: @BazzyTK use 'mysql_error()' to get the error after the query executes. Like usersomenumber down already proposed, the 'or die(mysql_error())' syntax may help you.

Comment: @nico Well, but it's the only thing that's 'wrong' with the posted code...though knowing the table structure might be worthwhile.

Comment: @ATaylor: agree with that, it is probably an issue somewhere else

Comment: @ATaylor Structure is:
id > name > message > date

Comment: @BazzyTK And what datatypes are we talking about? Put them in the original question please. Thank you.

Comment: @ATaylor: as said in another comment, he is not calling `mysql_select_db`

Comment: @nico Fun stuff...I noticed that myself (honest!), just now XD

Comment: @BazzyTK You're welcome. After all, we're here to help each other :)

Answer (score 2):

It is neccessary to first establish the database connection because the escape function is executed my mysql.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($m);
```

Comment: Ah yes, because it uses the encoding...my, my, I must really be getting sloppy.

Comment: Sadly I can't set 2 comments as the right one.. Would like to upvote this one, but can't since I haven't got nuff resp :(

Comment: @BazzyTK Allow me to do the honors. I included it in my answer too, but attributed Michael for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script with this code and post mysql_error

```
<?php
$act = $_POST['act'];
if($act == 1) {
$m = $_POST['message'];
$m = strip_tags($m);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($m);
$name = "Anonymous"; //Static username for demonstration purposes
$date = "2012-7-28"; //Static date for demonstration purposes

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (name, message, date) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$date')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
}
?>

<form action="comments.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="message">
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

UODATE>
The working code is follows:

```
<?php
$act = $_POST['act'];
if($act == 1) {
$m = $_POST['message'];
$m = strip_tags($m);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($m);
$name = "Anonymous"; //Static username for demonstration purposes
$date = "2012-7-28"; //Static date for demonstration purposes

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db('databasename');
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (name, message, date) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$date')") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_close($con);
}
?>

<form action="comments.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="message">
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Error is: No database selected

Comment: @BazzyTK: doesn't that error sound fairly [self-explanatory](http://us.php.net/mysql_select_db)? (Another bonus, PDO can be configured to throw exceptions on errors, no need to sprinkle `or die(mysql_error())` everywhere.)

Comment: @BazzyTK: right, you're not selecting the DB. Use `mysql_select_db`. Also, as DCoder suggests you should refrain to use `mysql_*` functions from new code. Use PDO instead.